# Why does RIGHT(@foostr, 0) return NULL when @foostr is varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string

In SQL Server 2005

If I want to find the right-most one character of a varchar(max) variable, no problem:

```
declare @foostr varchar(max)
set @foostr = 'abcd'
select right (@foostr, 1)

----
d
```

If I want to find the right-most zero characters of a string literal, no problem:

```
select right ('abcd', 0)

------------------
```

It returns an empty string.
If I want to find the right-most zero characters of a varchar(10), no problem:

```
declare @foostr varchar(10)
set @foostr = 'abcd'
select right (@foostr, 0)

----
```

It returns an empty string.
If I want to find the right-most zero characters of a varchar(max), well:

```
declare @foostr varchar(max)
set @foostr = 'abcd'
select right (@foostr, 0)

----    
NULL
```

It returns NULL.  Why?

Comment: I have to ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: just use: `ISNULL(right (@foostr, 0),'')` and you're good to go...

Comment: It was a while ago; I can't remember exactly - just for fun I was trying to write a string.reverse(), and I was iterating through a string and moving characters around, and on the last iteration the line:
set @string = substring(@string, @index, 1) + left(@string, @index) + right(@string, len(@string) - @index)
returned NULL instead of the final reversed string.  Or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an undefined behavior, as described in [the doc of `RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx),

> integer_expression
>
> > Is a positive integer that specifies how many characters of character_expression will be returned. If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned.

It does not specify what will return if it is 0.

Comment: Still, it's pretty odd that NULL is returned. Asking for 0 characters ought to give you a 0-length string.

Answer (score 0):

,1 not ,0  but returns '' for me anyway

```
declare @foostr varchar(max)
set @foostr = 'abcd'
select right (@foostr, 1)
```

why ,0  ????  what is the right most zero characters supposed to mean?

RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
integer_expression 
Is a **positive** integer that specifies how many characters of character_expression will be returned. If integer_expression is negative, an error is returned. If integer_expression is type bigint and contains a large value, character_expression must be of a large data type such as varchar(max).